# What does the "same as parent folder" mean in DNS?

Tags: active-directory

I was viewing the DNS management console and I noticed some records  having the name "same as parent folder" , so what does it mean and why it is called like this ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the domain name of the folder you are currently located in.

For example if you have "domain.com" and you navigate into the folder the "A" record for domain.com will show "same as parent folder" to indicate this is the "A" record for "domain.com"

Comment: thanks a lot mate , now clear